# How to check which SSH keys are currently 'active'?

Tags: ssh, security

How might one check which .rsa, .pem, and other files are 'loaded' or 'active' by `ssh-add`? I just had this scare:

```
$ scp -i /home/dotancohen/.ssh/dotancohen.pem someUser@1.2.3.4:~/files.tgz .
Warning: Identity file /home/dotancohen/.ssh/dotancohen.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
files.tgz                                                                100%   89MB   1.5MB/s   00:59
$ scp someUser@1.2.3.4:~/all_git.tgz . 
files.tgz                                                                100%   89MB   1.7MB/s   00:54
```

After verifying that the server does in fact require the `.pem` key, I would now like to know which other keys are loaded without me knowing about it!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As stated in `ssh-add`'s man page, the `-L` option allows you to view the public keys of the identities `ssh-agent` currently maintains. You could also use the `-l` option to view their fingerprints.

Comment: Thank you, I did in fact read the manpage but the wording did not convey to me what it does!

Answer (score 28):

There is a `-L` option of `ssh-add` that `L`ists public key parameters of all identities currently represented by the agent:

```
ssh-add -L
```